CBZ image concatenation in GoLang
I am trying to take a .cbz / comic book file, read the images into a single byte array and return it as a single image to serve in a web application. For testing purposes a .cbz file is just a rar with its extension changed, so you can create your own .cbz file by compressing a list of .jpg files and renaming the extension then try the code.
Here is my current code:
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/rendercbz", handleRenderCBZ)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func handleRenderCBZ(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Example path to .cbz file on the server filesystem
    filePath := "/home/my-home-dir/my-comic-book.cbz"

    // Open .cbz file from the filesystem
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Failed to open file: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Combine images from .cbz file into a single JPEG byte slice
    combinedData, err := combineImagesFromCBZ(file)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Failed to combine images from CBZ: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Serve the combined image as response
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
    if _, err := w.Write(combinedData); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Failed to write image response: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}

func combineImagesFromCBZ(file *os.File) ([]byte, error) {
    var combinedData []byte
    var imageCount int

    // Get file info to determine file size
    fileInfo, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to get file info: %v", err)
    }

    // Create a zip.Reader from the file
    reader, err := zip.NewReader(file, fileInfo.Size())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create zip reader: %v", err)
    }

    // Iterate through each file in the .cbz archive
    for _, zipFile := range reader.File {
        // Log which image is being processed
        log.Printf("Processing image: %s", zipFile.Name)

        // Skip files named "thumbnail.jpg" and non-image files
        if filepath.Base(zipFile.Name) == "thumbnail.jpg" {
            log.Printf("Skipping thumbnail file: %s", zipFile.Name)
            continue
        }
        ext := filepath.Ext(zipFile.Name)
        if ext != ".jpg" && ext != ".jpeg" && ext != ".png" && ext != ".gif" {
            log.Printf("Skipping non-image file: %s", zipFile.Name)
            continue
        }

        // Open each image file in the .cbz archive
        rc, err := zipFile.Open()
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Failed to open file in CBZ archive: %v", err)
            continue
        }

        // Read image file data
        fileData, err := io.ReadAll(rc)
        rc.Close()
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Failed to read file %s: %v", zipFile.Name, err)
            continue
        }

        // Validate that the image ends with 0xff, 0xd9
        if len(fileData) >= 2 && fileData[len(fileData)-2] == 0xff && fileData[len(fileData)-1] == 0xd9 {
            // Append image file data to combinedData
            combinedData = append(combinedData, fileData...)
            imageCount++
        } else {
            log.Printf("Invalid image ending for file: %s", zipFile.Name)
        }
    }

    // Append a single EOF marker to the end of combinedData
    combinedData = append(combinedData, []byte{0xff, 0xd9}...)

    // Log the final size of combinedData and the number of valid images found
    log.Printf("Final combinedData size = %d", len(combinedData))
    log.Printf("Number of valid images found: %d", imageCount)

    // Check if we have any data
    if len(combinedData) == 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("no valid image data found in CBZ file")
    }

    return combinedData, nil
}

And here is the corresponding console log:
> go run main.go
2024/07/10 07:33:44 Processing image: 01.jpg
2024/07/10 07:33:44 Processing image: 02.jpg
2024/07/10 07:33:44 Processing image: 03.jpg
2024/07/10 07:33:44 Processing image: 04.jpg
2024/07/10 07:33:44 Processing image: 05.jpg
2024/07/10 07:33:45 Processing image: 06.jpg
2024/07/10 07:33:45 Processing image: 07.jpg
2024/07/10 07:33:45 Processing image: 08.jpg
2024/07/10 07:33:45 Processing image: 09.jpg
2024/07/10 07:33:45 Processing image: 10.jpg
2024/07/10 07:33:45 Processing image: 11.jpg
2024/07/10 07:33:45 Processing image: ComicInfo.xml
2024/07/10 07:33:45 Skipping non-image file: ComicInfo.xml
2024/07/10 07:33:45 Processing image: thumbnail.jpg
2024/07/10 07:33:45 Skipping thumbnail file: thumbnail.jpg
2024/07/10 07:33:45 Final combinedData size = 35750599
2024/07/10 07:33:45 Number of valid images found: 11

If i compare the original first image within the archive and the downloaded image from the api. Even though the api only returned 1 image, the size is significantly different:

Original page 1 size: 5.01 MB
Downloaded page 1 size from api: 34.0 MB (34 MB is approximately the size of all the images combined individually)

Can someone spot why the api only returns the first image in the .cbz file when going to localhost:8080/rendercbz? It seems like there is something wrong with the built image that cuts off the remaining images from being rendered properly.
Note: I can't use jpeg.Encode since there are many large images inside the .cbz file causing this error: Failed to encode and send image: failed to encode image: jpeg: image is too large to encode.
I have gotten single page selection through a ?page=# query parameter to work, but wanted to explore if it possible to build a single image.

so the RAR file contains JPEG files. why don't you just serve those? why is any encoding involved at all?

Some comics are in a long scroll-able format (webtoon), so encoding all the images into one vertical image could be a good way to serve it. The other way is to lazy load each page as the web application loads (this is trivial).
But i wanted to try and see if this was possible to experiment.

I have seen web comics that slice their pages into thin horizontal ribbons... which is awful, but nothing that can't be fixed on the presentation side, which is the browser. a bunch of IMG elements and done.

Yeah I have seen that as well, I practically want to do the opposite. Take the individual images and format them into a single image at rest.

[mre] would be a good idea. strip everything irrelevant, such as the delivery over HTTP (and replace by trivial code, e.g. writing to disk). your goal seems to be to compose one large image from smaller ones, and then to encode that into a JPEG, in memory (not to disk).

Yes exactly, I opted out of going with the direct to disk example since I want to have all operations in memory. So this example is intentionally as it is.

I somewhat got it to work, but as expected it performs very poorly (maybe just because i'm currently on old hardware). If someone else wants to give it a try, or possible improve upon the work, feel free to.
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/draw"
    "image/jpeg"
    "image/png"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "sort"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/image/webp"
)

const (
    port         = 8080
    cbzDirectory = "./" // Directory where .cbz files are stored
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/webtoon", handleWebtoon)

    log.Printf("Server starting on port %d...\n", port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), nil))
}

func handleWebtoon(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != http.MethodGet {
        http.Error(w, "Method not allowed", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }

    filename := r.URL.Query().Get("file")
    if filename == "" {
        http.Error(w, "File parameter is required", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    if filepath.Ext(filename) != ".cbz" {
        http.Error(w, "Invalid file extension. Only .cbz files are allowed", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    filePath := filepath.Join(cbzDirectory, filepath.Clean(filename))

    if _, err := os.Stat(filePath); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        http.Error(w, "File not found", http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }

    img, err := CreateWebtoonStrip(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error creating webtoon strip: %v", err)
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Error processing file: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/png")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf("inline; filename=\"%s.png\"", filepath.Base(filename)))

    err = streamPNG(w, img)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error streaming PNG: %v", err)
        http.Error(w, "Error sending image", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}

func CreateWebtoonStrip(cbzFilePath string) (image.Image, error) {
    reader, err := zip.OpenReader(cbzFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error opening CBZ file: %v", err)
    }
    defer reader.Close()

    sort.Slice(reader.File, func(i, j int) bool {
        return reader.File[i].Name < reader.File[j].Name
    })

    var images []image.Image
    var totalHeight int
    var commonWidth int

    for _, file := range reader.File {
        if isImageFile(file.Name) {
            rc, err := file.Open()
            if err != nil {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("error opening file %s: %v", file.Name, err)
            }

            data, err := io.ReadAll(rc)
            rc.Close()
            if err != nil {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("error reading file %s: %v", file.Name, err)
            }

            img, format, err := decodeImage(bytes.NewReader(data))
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Error decoding file %s: %v", file.Name, err)
                continue // Skip this file and try the next one
            }

            log.Printf("Successfully decoded %s as %s", file.Name, format)

            width := img.Bounds().Dx()
            if commonWidth == 0 {
                commonWidth = width
            } else if width != commonWidth {
                log.Printf("Skipping %s: width %d doesn't match common width %d", file.Name, width, commonWidth)
                continue
            }

            images = append(images, img)
            totalHeight += img.Bounds().Dy()
        }
    }

    if len(images) == 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("no valid images found with matching width in the CBZ file")
    }

    finalImage := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, commonWidth, totalHeight))
    currentY := 0

    for _, img := range images {
        draw.Draw(finalImage, image.Rect(0, currentY, commonWidth, currentY+img.Bounds().Dy()), img, image.Point{}, draw.Src)
        currentY += img.Bounds().Dy()
    }

    return finalImage, nil
}

func isImageFile(filename string) bool {
    ext := strings.ToLower(filepath.Ext(filename))
    return ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".png" || ext == ".webp"
}

func decodeImage(r io.Reader) (image.Image, string, error) {
    data, err := io.ReadAll(r)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, "", fmt.Errorf("error reading image data: %v", err)
    }

    // Try decoding as JPEG
    img, err := jpeg.Decode(bytes.NewReader(data))
    if err == nil {
        return img, "jpeg", nil
    }

    // Try decoding as PNG
    img, err = png.Decode(bytes.NewReader(data))
    if err == nil {
        return img, "png", nil
    }

    // Try decoding as WebP
    img, err = webp.Decode(bytes.NewReader(data))
    if err == nil {
        return img, "webp", nil
    }

    return nil, "", fmt.Errorf("unsupported image format")
}

func streamPNG(w io.Writer, img image.Image) error {
    encoder := png.Encoder{
        CompressionLevel: png.DefaultCompression,
    }
    return encoder.Encode(w, img)
}

It is by no means perfect, but it does the job. Take any image where the width has a common size to not have dead space in the final image and render them as one MASSIVE image at rest.
With that said, I am sticking with lazy loading through a ?page=# query parameter.
Note: I had to abandon using jepg as the content type since JPEG has a max dimension of 65535x65535. When each page in the webtoon is around 12000 in height, and 720 in width, the dimension is quickly broken. So we decode jpegs, and return a large png. (which probably doesn't help with performance)
And i also uploaded it here: https://github.com/alexander-bruun/go-cbz-to-png/tree/main in case people want a fast git clone.
